# How to increment unique value inside an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my first question on stackoverflow.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var text = "<ul>";
  var item = $(".inputvalue").val();
  var n = checkvalue(myArray, item);
  if (!n)
  {
    myArray.push(item);
  }
  else
  {
    counter++;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
  {
    var valuetostring = "class" + i.toString();
    text += "<li class=" + valuetostring + ">" + myArray[i] + " x " + counter + "</li>";
  }
  $("#counter").text(counter);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3Low41j/2/

I need this solution to add a unique value to the array when a new value is typed in. If the same value is typed in, the number after the value should increment by one.

Like so:

- Sofa x 1
- Pillow x 4
- Chair x 1
- Table x 3

How would I do this?

My apologies if my code is a little amateurish, I've been working hard at this for two nights now and still can't figure it out.

Could you help me out please? Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to understand your code. It would help if you chose meaningful variable names for `foo, counter, bool, and bar. `

Comment: It would also be easier to help if you remove all the html related code and just leave the part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using an object like below, and then access that object for display rather than using an array. Keep in mind this is a stripped down version you would need to validate the input making sure it is in a format suitable to be a object key.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```js
var inputObj = {}; 

var entries = function(input){
    if(inputObj[input]== undefined){
        inputObj[input] = 1;
       
    }
    else{
        inputObj[input] += 1; 
    }

}

entries("hello"); 
entries("bye"); 
entries("hello");

//Object.keys, gives you an array of all keys in onject
console.log(Object.keys(inputObj))

//Display key property pairs for entire object
Object.keys(inputObj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, inputObj[key]);
});

//Access indivdual property
console.log("Hello Property = ", inputObj.hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you should stay using that api instead of mixing both native and jQuery, and You really should give your variables meaningful names to make it easier on future you, and anyone else that is viewing your code.

The main takeaway from this code is you can use an object literal `{}` to store the items added and their count. All items will be unique as you cannot have duplicate keys for an object.

```js
// use an object to store your items
const items = {};

const $input = $('.inputvalue')
const $output = $('#output')

// create a ul with your items and their counts
function render(items) {
  const $ul = $('<ul>')
  $.each(items, function(key, value) {
    $ul.append($(`<li>${key} x ${value}</li>`))
  })
  return $ul
}

$(".run1").click(function(e) {
  // get the value from the input field
  const item = $input.val()
  // if there is no item in the input return and do nothing
  if (item === '') {
    // you could show an error message here
    return false
  }
  // if no key for your item exists create it
  if (!items[item]) {
    // initialize to 0
    items[item] = 0
  }
  // increment your count, we can be sure we have an item at this point
  items[item] += 1
  // render your output
  $output.html(
    render(items)
  )
  console.log('items', items)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <input type="text" class="inputvalue">
  <button class="run1">
  RUN 1
</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <p id="counter"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Tested and working!

Please review the code comments and take advantage of the `reduce` function that will get the sum of the elements in the `Array`.

```js
// Global variables
const arr = [];

$('.run1').click(function() {
  let val = $('.inputvalue').val(),
      counterEl = $('#counter'),
      outputEl = $('#output'),
      outputHtml = '', 
      obj = {};
 
  // Sanitize
  val = $.trim(val);
 
  // Do nothing when dealing with empty values
  if (!val) {
    return;
  }
 
  // Add the value to the main array
  arr.push(val);
 
  // Create an object with totals
  obj = arr.reduce(function(accumulated, item){
    if (accumulated[item]) {
      accumulated[item] += 1;
    } else {
      accumulated[item] = 1;
    }
    return accumulated;
  }, {});
  
  // Build the HTML
  $.each(obj, function(key, count) {
    outputHtml += '<li>' + key + ' x ' + count + '</li>';
  });
 
  // Print the HTML and update the counter
  outputEl.html(outputHtml);
  counterEl.text(arr.length);
});
```

```css
.box {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* It's always a good practice to set this cursor for buttons */
.run1 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <input type="text" class="inputvalue">
  <button class="run1">
    RUN 1
  </button>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <p id="counter"></p>
</div>
```